# How can I put Tolkeins Elvish in Java

Tags: java, unicode

I'm wondering, I saw that [Tengwar, an Elvish language created by Tolkien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengwar#Encoding_schemes), has some Unicode values. How could I get them into a JavaFX window or console output? I just get a question mark in the console and a box in the JavaFX window.

I'm just trying to say hello in Elvish. The character I tried to use is Hyarmen. The website says that I'm supposed to use

```
"\u1xy28"
```

but that didn't work so I tried

```
"\E020"
```

which at least didn't give me an error. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to use a font that contains those characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `"\u1xy28"` is incorrect because it contains 2 non hexa characters `xy` after a `\u` prefix.

For the rest, according to the document from the official Unicode Consortium about [Special Areas and Format Characters](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch23.pdf)

> 23.5 Private-Use Characters
>
> Private-use characters are assigned Unicode code points whose interpretation is not specified
>   by this standard and whose use may be determined by private agreement among cooperating
>   users. These characters are designated for private use and do not have defined,
>   interpretable semantics except by private agreement.
>
> ...
>
> The primary Private Use Area consists of code points in the range U+E000 to U+F8FF, for
>   a total of 6,400 private-use characters.

That means that you can decide to use those code points for Tengwar characters, but you cannot hope that a standard font will know how to display them (because they are reserved for **private** use), and you will have to find a dedicated font.

Near the end of the wikipedia page you linked, you can find a link to [a comprehensive list of tengwar fonts](https://tengtelc.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/number-of-tengwar-fonts/)

I must say that I have not tested any of them...

Comment: Thanks, That helps a lot